# Why didn't the X-Jet use its cloak in X2?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2

In *X2* we see an aerial battle involving some U.S. fighter jets and the *X2*. Storm and Jean do everything they can to get away from the jets, and end up having to take them down. However, we know from *X-Men*, and *X-Men: The Last Stand*, that the X-Jet has an invisibility cloak; why not simply engage this, rather than endanger US pilots and having an aerial battle over continental US?

Comment: They might not have wanted to alert/inform the military/gouvernment that they possess this kind of technology. Maybe they wanted to wait until they escaped line of sight before activating their cloak. Additionally, a heat seeking missile, which the pilots could have fired at them either way, would most likely not have been fooled by the cloak.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that there was no visible cloak in X1. Storm simply created a fog around the jet and Scott turned on an infrared vision to see through it.

Answer (score 10):

According to the film's official novelisation, Kitty Pryde seems to have been responsible for developing the stealth technology being used to conceal the plane. In *X-Men* and *X2* she's still just a student at the school, hence why it wasn't installed into the jet until *X-Men 3: The Last Stand*.

> ***Cute little gizmo, he discovered, in keeping with its creator — full of surprises — it contained a miniature version of the holo-projection systems in the Blackbird and the Mansion,*** allowing him to view the target area in three dimensions rather than as a flat picture on a screen.
>
> <sub><sup>[X-Men: The Last Stand - Official Novelisation](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men:_The_Last_Stand_(novelization))</sup></sub>

For the record, in *X-Men* 1, there was no use of stealth technology. Storm created a fog to conceal their approach.

> “All right,” Cyclops said, “there’s the bridge. I’m taking us in. Storm, some cover please.”
>   “You got it,” Storm said. Her eyes went milky white.
>   As if to mirror those eyes, below, around, and under the G.W. Bridge a cloud of fog began to form over the calm, cold water. Cyclops watched as it began rolling down the Hudson River, past midtown Manhattan, then out toward Liberty Island.
>
> <sub><sup>[X-Men: Official Novelisation](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men:_A_Novelization)</sup></sub>